# How to determine the parent of a process like "ls"

Tags: command-line, process, ls

I've read methods of determining the parent of running processes but how would I determine the parent of a process thats lifecycle is too short to run a command like pstree without the process already have being finished?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question or scenario (and so *perhaps* I shouldn't answer it), but you give the example of the `ls` command, and how to determine its parent process since you can't examine it with something like `pstree` or `ps -efH`.

It would be nice to have the *reason* you need this information.  Otherwise I think we're looking at a bit of an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

In general, there's no way to get a PPID *retroactively*.  You need to capture it while the child process is running.

But for the question *as you asked it*, the answer seems straightforward.  The parent process for `ls` is/was always the process from which you launched it.  Typically, this will be the shell itself.

So if you run `ls` from inside `bash`, for example, the parent process *was*:

```
echo $$
```

That gives you the PID of the shell.

However, it's possible to make it more complicated, in a few ways.  You could run *another* shell that runs `ls`.  For instance:

```
sh -c "ls"
```

In that case, the parent process was the PID of `sh`, and since it has *also* completed execution, you won't be able to see its PID either through `pstree` or `ps`.

The solution for *that* would be to run something like:

```
sh -c 'echo $$; ls'
```

*Note the use of single quotes for allowing the `$$` to be unescaped.*

Perhaps, though, `ls` isn't going to be run by the shell, but perhaps from another application (maybe `vi`, maybe some Python script).

In that case, yes, wrap it with a script as per the [other existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1400259/1165986).  However, as it stands, that existing script can't handle *nested* execution.  For instance, running:

```
sh -c "./myls"
```

With that script will result in *two* parent processes being matched -- The `sh` line itself and the subprocess with `/bin/bash ./myls`.  You can see this by simply adding a `ps -ef` to the top of the script to get more info.

I believe a simplified, and more accurate version would simply be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PPID
ls
```

That uses the built-in shell variable `$PPID` to report the parent process of the script and will result in the true parent of the script itself.

One final corner-case to be aware of ...

```
sh -c "exec ./myls"
```

Will *not* report the PID of `sh` as its parent, since it's technically *not*.  The `myls` script will have *replaced* `sh` through the use of the `exec` command, meaning the PPID is that of the calling shell (`echo $$`) once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the workaround using small script and and the alias. The script replaces the command whose parent process you are looking for. The script name will be hidden behind the alias.

**1.** New script (e.g. `myls`) situated in `/usr/local/bin` and modified by `sudo chmod +x myls`:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=$(basename -- $0)
ps -ef | grep "$NAME" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print "** PARENT PROCESS = " $3; }'
ls
```

**Important note: Use only unique script name different from any process and command names.**

**2.** Create the `ls` alias for the `myls`:

```
alias ls=myls
```

**3.** Use `ls` command (in fact you will start `myls` command):

```
ls
```

**4.** Result

Example of fake `ls` command response, where:

- first line contains the parent process number (8481),
- second and next lines are response of the `ls` command placed at end of the `myls` script.

```
myname@mypc:/$ ls
** PARENT PROCESS = 8481
bin   cdrom  dev  fasthome  kdiskmark  libx32  lib64  mnt  proc  run   snap  sys  tmp  var
boot  data   etc  home      lib        lib32   media  opt  root  sbin  srv   s2   usr  vm
myname@mypc:/$
```

It is simplified solution, an example only. For real usage the script should be more precise to automate manual tasks, e.g. the `ls` or similar command placing at end of script, the alias creating/removing...

Comment: How about just `echo $PPID`?  The pattern matching in your current script matches twice for me if launched in a subprocess (e.g. `sh -c './myls'`).  In that case, it should match only the `sh` PID.